# herokuにpushしようとすると,No submodule mapping found in .gitmodules for path　***

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, heroku

こんにちは。

herokuにrailsアプリケーションをアップロードしようとすると以下のエラーがでます。

```
No submodule mapping found in .gitmodules for path'app/assets/stylesheets/includes/sanitize.css'
```

上記のパスをcacheで管理下から外すことや、`.git/config`のsubmoduleを削除するなど
試みましたが、解消せず。。。sanitize.cssはフォルダで、その中にsanitize.scssと周辺ファイルが入っています。

どうすれば治るでしょうか。お力をお貸しください。
よろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 0):

おそらく、 `app/assets/stylesheets/includes/sanitize.css` 自体、もしくはそこに至るまでのディレクトリのうちのどれかが、 `.git` を含む git レポジトリになっていると思われます。

そのレポジトリの `.git` を削除して git レポジトリでなくするか、 `git submodule` を利用して、その git レポジトリを submodule として登録するかのいずれかが必要だと思われます。